# step down 6V to 2V

Tags: voltage-regulator, heat

I have a 6v 4.5Ah lead acid battery. I need to step down the voltage to 2V to heat a nichrome wire. The wire need 1.7 A to get heated to required temperature. Any suggestions to step down the voltage?

Comment: Instead, you can use PWM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this buck converter would be suitable if you want a chip solution: -

[image]

It can have resistor values tweaked to produce 2 volts on the output and works with an input voltage in excess of your likely requirements. There are many such offerings if you don't want to build your own PWM circuit.

Comment: Will heat generate from the buck convertor? If so how do I control it?

Comment: It will be over 90% power efficient so, if your output power is 2 volts x 1.7 amps (=3.4 watts), the input power will be no more than 3.78 watts i.e. it will dissipate less than 400 mW. Alternatively you could buy a pre-built module for a few dollars from ebay. Try searching buck regulator.